# Ionic not reflecting Changes to parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, angularjs-routing

I have done this many time in `pure angular.js with ng-router` but dont know whats wrong with it here in `ionic using ui-router`

I want to have some $`scope` properties/objects on parent scope that i can read and modify from child scopes and they can reflect every where (**without factory**), so that refreshing between states doent loose data and i have common place to keep it

**What i have tried:**

I first tried whole app routes to be wrapped inside a div

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
     <div ui-view></div>
 </div>
```

This doesn't helped so i made app state as an `abstract` state and controller and now all states inherit from it

```
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    controller : 'appCtrl',
    templateUrl: "templates/app.html"
  })

     .state('app.login', {
    url: "/login",
    parent:"app",
    //abstract: true,
    controller : 'loginCtrl',
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html"
  })
      .state('app.form', {
    url: "/form/:selectedForm",
    //abstract: true,
    //reload:true,
    parent:"app",
    controller : 'formCtrl',
    templateUrl: "templates/selected-form.html"
  })
```

**Problem while trying:**

Problem is that lets say i have a property `$scope.selectedForm=21;` on `appCtrl` , i can access it correctly(shows 21 in all states) but `cant modify it` (`$scope.selectedForm=22;`) it doesnt reflects back

Dummy cotrollers

appctrl(parent):

```
 .controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.InspectedForms = [];
        $scope.currentForm= {}
        $scope.selectedForm=21;
    })
```

formCtrl(child):

```
 .controller('formCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, authService) {
             $scope.selectedForm=22;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was very obvious, how come I forgot about `dot rule`

Wasted my several hours, want to post it as if anyone else gets stuck to this kind of problem

Changes are only reflected on `objects and array` and `not on primitive types`

**Parent:**

```
app.controller('Parentctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.parentprimitive = "some primitive value"
    $scope.parentobj = {};
    $scope.parentobj.parentproperty = "somevalue";
});
```

**Child:**

```
app.controller('ctrlChild',function($scope){
    $scope.parentprimitive = "this will NOT modify the parent"
    $scope.parentobj.parentproperty = "this WILL modify the parent";
});
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) are details about the inheritance